# Adding FR language to Android App not possible

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, locale, french

When trying to add French to my app, when building it crashes on this:

```
Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\devapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fr\values-fr.xml
at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileTable(ResourceCompiler.kt:192)
at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.access$compileTable(ResourceCompiler.kt:1)
at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler$getCompileMethod$1.invoke(ResourceCompiler.kt:138)
at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler$getCompileMethod$1.invoke(ResourceCompiler.kt:138)
at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileResource(ResourceCompiler.kt:123)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@26f8f972.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@76fec1f4.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1d54bbcc.
    at com.android.aaptcompiler.TableExtractor.extractResourceValues(TableExtractor.kt:270)
    at com.android.aaptcompiler.TableExtractor.extract(TableExtractor.kt:181)
    at com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompiler.compileTable(ResourceCompiler.kt:188)
    ... 36 more
```

But English and Spanish are working just fine using the same method as French. I'm using the strings.xml translations editor for the language support. I did find out that It might be  the ' in the text. I tried doing `\'` or `&apos;` but this didn't help it either.

Comment: Alright found the issue, I also had to use the \ before a !. And the &apos; doesn't work anymore and I replaced all of them with \'

Comment: Thanks very much for this update! This was exactly what I needed to see. All the ASCII synonyms like &apos; was breaking my localization & build as well.